# ¿Cómo puedo iterar un DataFrame para hacer comparaciones de dos filas y como resultado cambiar una columna?

Tags: python, pandas, bucles, dataframe, comparaciones

Tengo un DataFrame con varias columnas, con datos como este ejemplo.

> ```
> index id    time sitio    carga     mov
> 0      1    1200   345       12     False
> 1      1    1210   345       12     False
> 2      1    1220   456       10     False
> 3      1    1230   456       10     False
> ```

Necesito ir comparando una fila con la siguiente, por ejemplo `index[0]` con `index[1]`.

- Si la carga es igual, aumento indices del bucle a `index[1]` con `index[2]`
- Si la carga de las dos filas es distinta, cambio el valor de la columna `mov` a `True` en ambas(`index[1]` y `index[2]`), y cambio los indices del bucle para pasar las siguientes dos `index[3]` e `index[4]`.

Este es el código que intento:

```
for i in range(len(fila)):   #para hacerlo en todo el dataframe
    j=i+1       #para el segundo indice
    if fila[i].carga!=fila[j].carga:   #si las cargas son distintas
        fila[i].mov(True)     #cambiamos las dos columnas mov a true
        fila[j].mov(True)
        i=+  #como ponemos a true dos filas, aumentamos en 2 los indices
        j=+2
        else:
            i=+   #si las cargas son iguales seguimos
            j=+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos a crear un ejemplo reproducible basado en el tuyo primero:

```
import io

import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO("""\n               
index id    time sitio    carga     mov
0      1    1200   345       12     False
1      1    1210   345       12     False
2      1    1220   456       10     False
3      1    1230   456       14     False
4      1    1230   456       14     False
5      1    1230   456       17     False
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+", engine="python")
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>    index  id  time  sitio  carga    mov
> 0      0   1  1200    345     12  False
> 1      1   1  1210    345     12  False
> 2      2   1  1220    456     10  False
> 3      3   1  1230    456     14  False
> 4      4   1  1230    456     14  False
> 5      5   1  1230    456     17  False
> ```

Si no lo tienes ya, te aconsejo que hagas que la columna `index` sea el índice del DataFrame (valga la redundancia), te facilitará la iteración:

```
df.set_index("index", inplace=True)
```

En cuanto a tu problema, incrementar la variable `i` asociada al ciclo no sirve de nada porque en la siguiente iteración el propio ciclo le dará un nuevo valor en base al item obtenido de `range`, dejando sin efecto tu incremento.

- Podrías usar un ciclo `while`:

  ```
  i = 0
  max_index = len(df)
  while i < max_index:
      j = i + 1
      if df.at[i, "carga"] != df.at[j, "carga"]:
          df.at[i, "mov"] = True
          df.at[j, "mov"] = True
          i += 2
      i += 1
  ```
- Se podría usar `range` como haces en tu ejemplo en este caso. Para saltar la iteración podemos usar  un condicional y una variable bandera:

  ```
  saltar_iter = False
  for i in range(len(df) - 1):
      j = i + 1
      if saltar_iter:
          saltar_iter = False
      elif df.at[i, "carga"] != df.at[j, "carga"]:
          df.at[i, "mov"] = True
          df.at[j, "mov"] = True
          saltar_iter = True
  ```

  pero **si tu índice no es continuo o si no es de enteros directamente fallaría**.
- Mejor aún, puedes usar `zip` para  iterar a la par sobre los indices y sobre los índices menos el primer elemento, generando de esta forma los índices de cada columna en cada iteración de la forma `(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), ....`.

  Cuando la condición se cumpla puedes "saltarte" una iteración del `for` consumiendo un item del iterable generado por `zip` con `next`.

  ```
  roll_iter = zip(df.index, df.index[1:])
  for i, j in roll_iter:
      if df.at[i, "carga"] != df.at[j, "carga"]:
          df.at[i, "mov"] = True
          df.at[j, "mov"] = True
          try:
              next(roll_iter)
          except StopIteration:
              break
  ```

  o usando el condicional para saltarse la iteración:

  ```
  saltar_iter = False
  for i, j in zip(df.index, df.index[1:]):
      if saltar_iter:
          saltar_iter = False
      elif df.at[i, "carga"] != df.at[j, "carga"]:
          df.at[i, "mov"] = True
          df.at[j, "mov"] = True
          saltar_iter = True
  ```

  En este caso no importa si tu índice no es continuo o no es de enteros directamente. Basta con que los índices sea únicos.
- En el caso de que los índices no sean únicos tampoco, podemos hacer algo como:

  ```
  saltar_iter = False
  mov_col_idx = df.columns.get_loc('mov')
  carga_col_idx = df.columns.get_loc('carga')
  for i in range(len(df) - 1):
      j = i + 1
      if saltar_iter:
          saltar_iter = False
      elif df.iat[df.index[i], carga_col_idx] != df.iat[j, carga_col_idx]:
          df.iat[i, mov_col_idx] = True
          df.iat[j, mov_col_idx] = True
          saltar_iter = True
  ```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>        id  time  sitio  carga    mov
> index                               
> 0       1  1200    345     12  False
> 1       1  1210    345     12   True
> 2       1  1220    456     10   True
> 3       1  1230    456     14  False
> 4       1  1230    456     14   True
> 5       1  1230    456     17   True
> ```

Comment: Muchicismas gracias. Eres una máquina.